# Custom control in reference does not render correctly

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, resources, reference

I have made a custom control (round button with a fixed image) and tested that it works. However, I would like to reuse this particular control in other projects and hence thought of making a class library out of it. However, when I try to get the custom control to show in my other applications, the icons does not show even though the button responds to clicks.

I have tried to build the icon in the class library projects as Content and Resources and test but to no avail. (of course, I change the addressing of the icon in the code when I updated its build icon). At the moment, i have decided to leave the icon /icons/myimage.png to be built as Content. And, in the class library code (XAML), i am accessing it as "/icons/myimage.png".

So, would anyone have an idea on how I could get the round button to render properly in my projects? How should I build the class library project?

Comment: What uri are have you tried with the Resource build action?

Comment: @Georgi Stoyanov - So, this is as it has been configured in the Reference DLL: Icon is stored as a resource <local:RoundButton x:Name="ConnectButton" Icon="/MyLib;component/icons/connect.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>. And when icon is built as Content, <local:RoundButton x:Name="ConnectButton" Icon="/icons/connect.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>. MyLib is the Assembly that get's created when Class library project is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented a bit and found the solution. The idea is to use **embedded resource** to store the image in the dll. And then for loading it by the CustomControl, one can use constructs like this:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetSource(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyLib.icons.my_icon.png"));
```

MyLib here is the name of the assembly for the class library. icons is the folder where the resource is kept in the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I would't make a graphics part of my class library, because most likely in the future you will need to customize it, so what I suggest is to make the following property in your custom module and set the image where you use it:

```
public ImageSource ButtonImage {get { return <button image>; } set {  <set button image>; } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, in this particular case, the icon on that control would not change throughout the various projects. I understand your point but, i do not want the configure that control in every project. Would you have a suggestion to what i want to achieve?